# Python turtle.onkey doesn't run function

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is my code:

```
import turtle

# window
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)


def hi():
    print("hi")

def bye():
    print("bye")


wn.listen()
wn.onkey(hi, "a")
wn.onkeyrelease(bye, "a")


while True:
    wn.update()
```

When I press the key, it doesn't print "hi", but when I release the key it prints "bye" just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

onkey is just alias for onkeyrelease

Use onkeypress instead

```
wn.onkeypress(hi, "a")
wn.onkeyrelease(bye, "a")
```

Comment: I don't use onkeypress because when you hold the key down, it runs the function repeatedly, but I only want to run it once. Is that achievable through another way?

Comment: set a boolean flag at first call. ignore next calls, unset flag on keyrelease.